# wrap till fills parent android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app where i need that title `TextView` would `wrap_content` (in horizontal `LinearLayout`), but after it i have two other views that should `wrap_content` as well.

Title is long and could take whole screen.

Other two views takes 100dp at most (no actual limits).

In illustration my goal is to do something like `wrap_till_fill_empty_space`

[image: Image that shows the problem]

I have xml that looks like this:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="BLABLASONG sd asd "/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherV1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="180.5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherV2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ms"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

But the title always takes all the empty space like `AND` part of the illustration.

**UPDATE**
Solved it by changing root element `match_parent` to `wrap_content` and, as appropriate for weight, setting title layout_width="0dp".

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="BLABLASONG sd asd "/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherV1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="180.5"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherV2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ms"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Putting `android:layout_weight="1"` in the linearlayout that has both textviews doesn't work?

Comment: Doesn't work. but just found the solution that root element of given xml would also wrap_content.